# Django url unit test comparison of expected view function fails

Tags: django, django-tests

```
class TestsUrls(SimpleTestCase):

def test_index_url_is_resolved(self):
    url = reverse('index')
    self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, index)
```

I am trying to unit test url to see if it returns the expected view. This assertion fails even though it looks like the functions are the same. I am using function based views, not class based views. Does that have something to do with it?

```
AssertionError: <function index at 0x11db7cb70> != <function index at 0x11d860ae8>
```

Comment: everything in python is an object, even a function. You're instantiating the same function multiple times (in different ways) so when you compare them you will get `False` because they are two different objects in memory

Comment: You could test that `f.__name__` and `f.__module__` are the same for both functions.

Comment: basically this:  self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.__name__, index.__name__)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you get `index`, but `resolve(url).func` returns an instance of the python **object** that is the function. Everything in python are objects, also functions, so you get an **instance** in memory. When you compare the two objects, you are comparing different **instances** of the same function. As you can see their addresses in memory are different.

So instead of directly comparing them, compare their name and module:

```
f = resolve(url).func
self.assertEqual(f.__name__, index.__name__)
self.assertEqual(f.__module__, index.__module__)
```